# SSIS copy data from SQL db to multiple tabs on the same excel destination

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, excel-tables

I've got an SSIS package that loads data from a flat file source into a table within a SQL Server Database i then have a SQL task to get specific data and load into an excel destination, i want to add another SQL task to load different data into the same excel workbook but on a different tab is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You can use same excel file to save diffrent data sets in different worksheets. In *Excel destination editor* for **Excel Destination** component press **[New]** button and change name of the table in **CREATE TABLE** statment to name of the worksheet you want to use. After that select new it as a worksheet name.

[image]

Comment: thanks for that. do you know how to map fields when setting the location on the excel workbook for the data to go. as soon as i select location my mappings change. and i cant change them